# How to migrate from Delphi6 to Delphi2010 (Unicode Problem)

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-2010, delphi-6

Hi I was using the Francois Piette's RasDial with Delphi 6, but it stopped working in Delphi 2010
How can I keep using these functions like before?

```
class function Encryption.DecriptPasswd(strPasswd: string): string;  
type  
  PWORD = ^WORD;  
var  
   Buffer : String;  
   PW : String[255];
   P : PWORD;
   I : Integer;  
   V : Integer;
begin                                                                
  PW := ' ';                                                         
  P := PWORD(@PW[0]);                                                
  I := 1;                                                            
  while I <= Length(strPasswd) do                                    
  begin                                                              
    Buffer := Copy(strPasswd, I, 5);                                 
    I := I + 5;                                                      
    V := StrToInt(Buffer) - 34567;                                   
    P^ := V;                                                         
    Inc(P);                                                          
  end;                                                               
  Result := PW;                                                      
end;                                                                 

class function Encryption.EncriptPasswd(strPasswd: string): string;  
type                                                                 
  PWORD = ^WORD;                                                     
var                                                                   
  Len : Integer;                                                       
  I : Integer;                                                         
  V : DWORD;  
  P : PChar;  
  Buffer : String[255];  
begin  
  Buffer := strPasswd;  
  Len := Length(Buffer) + 1;  
  if (Len mod 2) <> 0 then  
    Inc(Len);  

  if Len < 10 then  
    Len := 10;  

  I := Length(Buffer);  
  if I = 0 then  
    Buffer := IntToStr(GetTickCount)  
  else  
    while Length(Buffer) < 10 do  
      Buffer := Buffer + Buffer;  
  SetLength(Buffer, I);  

  Result := '';  
  P := PChar(@Buffer[0]);  
  for I := 1 to Len div 2 do  
  begin  
    V := 34567 + PWORD(P)^;  
    P := P + 2;  
    Result := Result + Format('%5.5d', [V]);  
  end;  
end;
```

Comment: Jiraya, welcome to SO!  I tagged your question 'delphi'.  You had tags for specific versions but it's a far more general question (someone upgrading from D7 to DXE might encounter the same problem, for example.)  Also I have a watched tag for 'delphi' and similar subtags like 'delphi-6' don't show up for it - I came across this by accident.

Comment: If it's Francois PIETTE's code, you might want to post to http://lists.elists.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/delphi because he's still active over there - and I haven't seen him over here.

Answer (score 3):

You can start by changing all `string` declarations (except the `string[255]` ones, which already are) to `AnsiString`, all `Char` to `AnsiChar`, and all `PChar` to `PAnsiChar`.

Then go [here](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38437) for the first in a series of three articles on porting pre-Unicode versions of Delphi to Unicode. They're really well written by [Nick Hodges](http://www.nickhodges.com), former Product Manager for Delphi when it was a CodeGear product. They cover all the details you need to make the changes to your other existing code.

Answer (score 1):

String[255] is short string (one byte)
but when you add pchar, it grows two bytes by two bytes

try replace pchar by pansichar